# Unable to discover peer when after deploying the substrate node template

Tags: substrate-node-template, network

I am using the substrate node template binary in 2 ubuntu servers and their IPs are

10.100.20.1 and 10.100.20.2
Host names are `telsher001` and `telsher002`

Im following this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/ to simulate a network

I am using  the exact run commands as follows in 2 machines

On 1st VM machine 10.100.20.1 I'm running the genesis node as follows

```
./substrate-node-template --base-path /tmp/alice --chain local --alice --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933 --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 --rpc-methods Unsafe --validator
```

On the 2nd VM machine 10.100.20.2
Im using the following command to run the project

```
./substrate-node-template
--base-path /tmp/bob --chain local --bob --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933 --validator --bootnodes /ip4/10.100.20.2/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWEyoppNCUx8Yx66oV9fJnriXwCcXwDDUA2kj6vnc6iDEp
```

In both terminals, there are no errors, but Peer discovery is not happening
Im looking for a way to get the peer discovery working

Even I checked firewall settings on both VMs which look like this. Please note that these virtual machines does not have access to outside internet

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
30333                      ALLOW       Anywhere
9933                       ALLOW       Anywhere
9944                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
30333 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9933 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9944 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I am looking a solution for this
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The genesis might be different.

Try to build the spec file and use it as the chain.

```
./node build-spec --raw --chain local > local.json
# Copy the local.json to the VMs
./node --chain local.json
```